# get token, store it, refresh it if expired using oauth2 gem in ruby

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api, ruby-2.1

I am working on script to get google contacts using [google contacts api gem](https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api). I am able to access the token successfully using this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'launchy'
require 'oauth2'
require 'googlecontacts'
require 'google_contacts_api'

# Get your credentials from the console
CLIENT_ID = 'your Id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'your Secret'
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,site: 'https://accounts.google.com',token_url: '/o/oauth2/token', authorize_url: '/o/oauth2/auth')
url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(scope: OAUTH_SCOPE, redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI)
Launchy.open(url)
$stdout.write  "Enter authorization code: "
code = gets.chomp
token = client.auth_code.get_token(code, :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
```

> **PROBLEM:**

I know that this is not the best way to do it, because it is tiring. every time I run the script the user has give access instructions. And also I have to manually copy paste the token from the browser to the terminal.

> **QUESTION:**

How can be able to store the retrieved token, and when it expired how can I refresh it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [oauth2 library](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) to get the access token. The [AccessToken class](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb) has `to_hash()` and `from_hash()` methods, which you can use to serialize and deserialize the token once you've gotten it, as well as a `refresh()` method to refresh the access token once it's expired. If this is a command line script you can use a hidden file in the user's home directory to store the serialized token.

Comment: what I am not understanding is: "what can I add in the above code so as to return an hash with the access token and also the refresh token?". thats the problem. I mean something like this: {
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}

Comment: When you run `client.auth_code.get_token` method, the response will be a `AccessToken` object. And as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb), this class has all the info you want, like `token`, `refresh_token`, expire info, and a method to refresh the auth.

Comment: I got a way. Thanks Rael & Eric for your answer. I am now able to access the refresh token. I am going to find a way to use it for exchange of a new token once it expires.

Comment: from the above code: the access token will be token.token. Refresh token: token.refresh_token. Expires at: token.expires_at. And so on...

Answer (score 3):

During the first authentication, you got an authorization token and a refresh token.

Store the refresh_token (in session if it's a web app, or any other "volatile" persistence scheme, or in last case in database).

Using the refresh_token, ask for a new token like described in [Google OAuth2 WebServer documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh).

If this is not a webserver application, maybe you should consider use other [OAuth2 authentication flows](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/).

Comment: exactly it is not a webserver application. Under google developers application console, I have used the application type as INSTALLED APPLICATION. 
..I have seen authentication using OAUTH2 flows like here https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/blob/master/drive/drive.rb. I can implement this, but the only problem is how I can get that specific access token.
maybe you can help me on how to get that token only. thanks for the ans.

Comment: Right, so the Google doc for installed applications is located [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp). Anyway, your user will face a browser window asking grants. And again, you'll receive 2 tokens, one for authorization, and other for refresh. As all requests are only HTTP requests, maybe you can use the rest-client gem to follow the documentation. May I ask you your goal? Maybe import contacts?

Comment: yes, to import all the email addresses. any ideas which can make me do it better? And also I tried following the google doc and it is opening the window where I should copy paste the token to the terminal.I had one problem: how to automatically get the token as they are suggesting in the documentation.

Comment: Well, I work at Cloudsponge, a service to import contacts for several sources (Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, Linkedin, Facebook, etc), and it's free to test. You can see our HTML widget on the [Test-Drive page](http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive) or you can use our [API for several languages](http://cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail). If you want partial solutions, you can use [omniauth gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth).

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive a refresh token, you need to [alter the url](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline).

in OAuth2:

`url = client.auth_code.authorize_url(scope: OAUTH_SCOPE, access_type: "offline", redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI)`

Then it will be available like Erik Koleda mentions.